Possible MathJax upgrade
Since not all interested users frequent meta.SE, here’s a heads up that some work is underway towards the possibility of upgrading MathJax v2 to v3 or v4 on Stack Exchange sites including cstheory. It is still in experimental stage, but any registered user can test it themselves by turning MathJax v3 on in profile preferences (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/).
See Upgrade plans for MathJax v3/v4 for the full announcement with many more details.

Thanks for x-posting Emil!
